# Make horizontal scrollbar visible all the time if necessary without vertical scrolling

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make data grid like layout where left side is frozen and only right side is scrollable. However, whole div needs to be vertically scrollable. The idea is working as you would see but the horizontal scrollbar is way on the bottom I would like to make it visible all the time if scrolling is necessary.

```css
/* ! tailwindcss v3.0.24 | MIT License | https://tailwindcss.com */

/*
1. Prevent padding and border from affecting element width. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/4)
2. Allow adding a border to an element by just adding a border-width. (https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/pull/116)
*/

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* 1 */
  border-width: 0;
  /* 2 */
  border-style: solid;
  /* 2 */
  border-color: #e5e7eb;
  /* 2 */
}

::before,
::after {
  --tw-content: '';
}

/*
1. Use a consistent sensible line-height in all browsers.
2. Prevent adjustments of font size after orientation changes in iOS.
3. Use a more readable tab size.
4. Use the user's configured `sans` font-family by default.
*/

html {
  line-height: 1.5;
  /* 1 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  -moz-tab-size: 4;
  /* 3 */
  tab-size: 4;
  /* 3 */
  font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  /* 4 */
}

/*
1. Remove the margin in all browsers.
2. Inherit line-height from `html` so users can set them as a class directly on the `html` element.
*/

body {
  margin: 0;
  /* 1 */
  line-height: inherit;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
1. Add the correct height in Firefox.
2. Correct the inheritance of border color in Firefox. (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=190655)
3. Ensure horizontal rules are visible by default.
*/

hr {
  height: 0;
  /* 1 */
  color: inherit;
  /* 2 */
  border-top-width: 1px;
  /* 3 */
}

/*
Add the correct text decoration in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.
*/

abbr:where([title]) {
  -webkit-text-decoration: underline dotted;
          text-decoration: underline dotted;
}

/*
Remove the default font size and weight for headings.
*/

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
}

/*
Reset links to optimize for opt-in styling instead of opt-out.
*/

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

/*
Add the correct font weight in Edge and Safari.
*/

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

/*
1. Use the user's configured `mono` font family by default.
2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
*/

code,
kbd,
samp,
pre {
  font-family: ui-monospace, SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
  /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Add the correct font size in all browsers.
*/

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

/*
Prevent `sub` and `sup` elements from affecting the line height in all browsers.
*/

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

/*
1. Remove text indentation from table contents in Chrome and Safari. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=999088, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201297)
2. Correct table border color inheritance in all Chrome and Safari. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=935729, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195016)
3. Remove gaps between table borders by default.
*/

table {
  text-indent: 0;
  /* 1 */
  border-color: inherit;
  /* 2 */
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* 3 */
}

/*
1. Change the font styles in all browsers.
2. Remove the margin in Firefox and Safari.
3. Remove default padding in all browsers.
*/

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  font-size: 100%;
  /* 1 */
  line-height: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  color: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  margin: 0;
  /* 2 */
  padding: 0;
  /* 3 */
}

/*
Remove the inheritance of text transform in Edge and Firefox.
*/

button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}

/*
1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
2. Remove default button styles.
*/

button,
[type='button'],
[type='reset'],
[type='submit'] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* 1 */
  background-color: transparent;
  /* 2 */
  background-image: none;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Use the modern Firefox focus style for all focusable elements.
*/

:-moz-focusring {
  outline: auto;
}

/*
Remove the additional `:invalid` styles in Firefox. (https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/2f9eacd9d3d995c937b4251a5557d95d494c9be1/layout/style/res/forms.css#L728-L737)
*/

:-moz-ui-invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}

/*
Add the correct vertical alignment in Chrome and Firefox.
*/

progress {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/*
Correct the cursor style of increment and decrement buttons in Safari.
*/

::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto;
}

/*
1. Correct the odd appearance in Chrome and Safari.
2. Correct the outline style in Safari.
*/

[type='search'] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  /* 1 */
  outline-offset: -2px;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Remove the inner padding in Chrome and Safari on macOS.
*/

::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/*
1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
2. Change font properties to `inherit` in Safari.
*/

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* 1 */
  font: inherit;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Add the correct display in Chrome and Safari.
*/

summary {
  display: list-item;
}

/*
Removes the default spacing and border for appropriate elements.
*/

blockquote,
dl,
dd,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
hr,
figure,
p,
pre {
  margin: 0;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

legend {
  padding: 0;
}

ol,
ul,
menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*
Prevent resizing textareas horizontally by default.
*/

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

/*
1. Reset the default placeholder opacity in Firefox. (https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/3300)
2. Set the default placeholder color to the user's configured gray 400 color.
*/

input::placeholder,
textarea::placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
  /* 1 */
  color: #9ca3af;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Set the default cursor for buttons.
*/

button,
[role="button"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*
Make sure disabled buttons don't get the pointer cursor.
*/

:disabled {
  cursor: default;
}

/*
1. Make replaced elements `display: block` by default. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/14)
2. Add `vertical-align: middle` to align replaced elements more sensibly by default. (https://github.com/jensimmons/cssremedy/issues/14#issuecomment-634934210)
   This can trigger a poorly considered lint error in some tools but is included by design.
*/

img,
svg,
video,
canvas,
audio,
iframe,
embed,
object {
  display: block;
  /* 1 */
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Constrain images and videos to the parent width and preserve their intrinsic aspect ratio. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/14)
*/

img,
video {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/*
Ensure the default browser behavior of the `hidden` attribute.
*/

[hidden] {
  display: none;
}

*, ::before, ::after {
  --tw-translate-x: 0;
  --tw-translate-y: 0;
  --tw-rotate: 0;
  --tw-skew-x: 0;
  --tw-skew-y: 0;
  --tw-scale-x: 1;
  --tw-scale-y: 1;
  --tw-pan-x:  ;
  --tw-pan-y:  ;
  --tw-pinch-zoom:  ;
  --tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity;
  --tw-ordinal:  ;
  --tw-slashed-zero:  ;
  --tw-numeric-figure:  ;
  --tw-numeric-spacing:  ;
  --tw-numeric-fraction:  ;
  --tw-ring-inset:  ;
  --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;
  --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff;
  --tw-ring-color: rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);
  --tw-ring-offset-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-blur:  ;
  --tw-brightness:  ;
  --tw-contrast:  ;
  --tw-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-invert:  ;
  --tw-saturate:  ;
  --tw-sepia:  ;
  --tw-drop-shadow:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-blur:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-brightness:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-contrast:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-invert:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-opacity:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-saturate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-sepia:  ;
}

.m-10 {
  margin: 2.5rem;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.h-80 {
  height: 20rem;
}

.w-96 {
  width: 24rem;
}

.w-28 {
  width: 7rem;
}

.flex-1 {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
}

.flex-row {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.overflow-x-hidden {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.overflow-y-hidden {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.overflow-x-scroll {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.overflow-y-scroll {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.border {
  border-width: 1px;
}

.border-l {
  border-left-width: 1px;
}

.pl-4 {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="m-10 flex h-80 w-96 flex-row flex-wrap overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll border">
  <div class="w-28 pl-4">
    <div>1111111</div>
    <div>1111111</div>
    <div>2222222</div>
    <div>2222222</div>
    <div>3333333</div>
    <div>3333333</div>
    <div>4444444</div>
    <div>4444444</div>
    <div>5555555</div>
    <div>5555555</div>
    <div>6666666</div>
    <div>6666666</div>
    <div>7777777</div>
    <div>7777777</div>
    <div>8888888</div>
    <div>8888888</div>
    <div>9999999</div>
    <div>9999999</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-1 overflow-y-hidden overflow-x-scroll border-l pl-4" style="scrollbar-gutter: stable both-edges">
    <div class="w-96">
      <div>1111111</div>
      <div>1111111</div>
      <div>2222222</div>
      <div>2222222</div>
      <div>3333333</div>
      <div>3333333</div>
      <div>4444444</div>
      <div>4444444</div>
      <div>5555555</div>
      <div>5555555</div>
      <div>6666666</div>
      <div>6666666</div>
      <div>7777777</div>
      <div>7777777</div>
      <div>8888888</div>
      <div>8888888</div>
      <div>9999999</div>
      <div>9999999</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there anyway to make horizontal scrollbar visible all the time.

Comment: you want the right side table to have it's horizontal scrollbar fixed like visible all the time?

Answer (score 1):

I added a class to the main parent called `perm-scroll`. Then you can use this class to create a `::-webkit-scrollbar`. When adding a `-webkit-scrollbar` directly on an element with `overflow-y: scroll;` it will display those styles and the scrollbar all the time. See below:

```css
/* ! tailwindcss v3.0.24 | MIT License | https://tailwindcss.com */


/*
1. Prevent padding and border from affecting element width. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/4)
2. Allow adding a border to an element by just adding a border-width. (https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/pull/116)
*/

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* 1 */
  border-width: 0;
  /* 2 */
  border-style: solid;
  /* 2 */
  border-color: #e5e7eb;
  /* 2 */
}

::before,
::after {
  --tw-content: '';
}


/*
1. Use a consistent sensible line-height in all browsers.
2. Prevent adjustments of font size after orientation changes in iOS.
3. Use a more readable tab size.
4. Use the user's configured `sans` font-family by default.
*/

html {
  line-height: 1.5;
  /* 1 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  -moz-tab-size: 4;
  /* 3 */
  tab-size: 4;
  /* 3 */
  font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  /* 4 */
}


/*
1. Remove the margin in all browsers.
2. Inherit line-height from `html` so users can set them as a class directly on the `html` element.
*/

body {
  margin: 0;
  /* 1 */
  line-height: inherit;
  /* 2 */
}


/*
1. Add the correct height in Firefox.
2. Correct the inheritance of border color in Firefox. (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=190655)
3. Ensure horizontal rules are visible by default.
*/

hr {
  height: 0;
  /* 1 */
  color: inherit;
  /* 2 */
  border-top-width: 1px;
  /* 3 */
}


/*
Add the correct text decoration in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.
*/

abbr:where([title]) {
  -webkit-text-decoration: underline dotted;
  text-decoration: underline dotted;
}


/*
Remove the default font size and weight for headings.
*/

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
}


/*
Reset links to optimize for opt-in styling instead of opt-out.
*/

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}


/*
Add the correct font weight in Edge and Safari.
*/

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
}


/*
1. Use the user's configured `mono` font family by default.
2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
*/

code,
kbd,
samp,
pre {
  font-family: ui-monospace, SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
  /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em;
  /* 2 */
}


/*
Add the correct font size in all browsers.
*/

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}


/*
Prevent `sub` and `sup` elements from affecting the line height in all browsers.
*/

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}


/*
1. Remove text indentation from table contents in Chrome and Safari. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=999088, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201297)
2. Correct table border color inheritance in all Chrome and Safari. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=935729, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195016)
3. Remove gaps between table borders by default.
*/

table {
  text-indent: 0;
  /* 1 */
  border-color: inherit;
  /* 2 */
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* 3 */
}


/*
1. Change the font styles in all browsers.
2. Remove the margin in Firefox and Safari.
3. Remove default padding in all browsers.
*/

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  font-size: 100%;
  /* 1 */
  line-height: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  color: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  margin: 0;
  /* 2 */
  padding: 0;
  /* 3 */
}


/*
Remove the inheritance of text transform in Edge and Firefox.
*/

button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}


/*
1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
2. Remove default button styles.
*/

button,
[type='button'],
[type='reset'],
[type='submit'] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* 1 */
  background-color: transparent;
  /* 2 */
  background-image: none;
  /* 2 */
}


/*
Use the modern Firefox focus style for all focusable elements.
*/

:-moz-focusring {
  outline: auto;
}


/*
Remove the additional `:invalid` styles in Firefox. (https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/2f9eacd9d3d995c937b4251a5557d95d494c9be1/layout/style/res/forms.css#L728-L737)
*/

:-moz-ui-invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}


/*
Add the correct vertical alignment in Chrome and Firefox.
*/

progress {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/*
Correct the cursor style of increment and decrement buttons in Safari.
*/

::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto;
}


/*
1. Correct the odd appearance in Chrome and Safari.
2. Correct the outline style in Safari.
*/

[type='search'] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  /* 1 */
  outline-offset: -2px;
  /* 2 */
}


/*
Remove the inner padding in Chrome and Safari on macOS.
*/

::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}


/*
1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
2. Change font properties to `inherit` in Safari.
*/

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* 1 */
  font: inherit;
  /* 2 */
}


/*
Add the correct display in Chrome and Safari.
*/

summary {
  display: list-item;
}


/*
Removes the default spacing and border for appropriate elements.
*/

blockquote,
dl,
dd,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
hr,
figure,
p,
pre {
  margin: 0;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

legend {
  padding: 0;
}

ol,
ul,
menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*
Prevent resizing textareas horizontally by default.
*/

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}


/*
1. Reset the default placeholder opacity in Firefox. (https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/3300)
2. Set the default placeholder color to the user's configured gray 400 color.
*/

input::placeholder,
textarea::placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
  /* 1 */
  color: #9ca3af;
  /* 2 */
}


/*
Set the default cursor for buttons.
*/

button,
[role="button"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*
Make sure disabled buttons don't get the pointer cursor.
*/

:disabled {
  cursor: default;
}


/*
1. Make replaced elements `display: block` by default. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/14)
2. Add `vertical-align: middle` to align replaced elements more sensibly by default. (https://github.com/jensimmons/cssremedy/issues/14#issuecomment-634934210)
   This can trigger a poorly considered lint error in some tools but is included by design.
*/

img,
svg,
video,
canvas,
audio,
iframe,
embed,
object {
  display: block;
  /* 1 */
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* 2 */
}


/*
Constrain images and videos to the parent width and preserve their intrinsic aspect ratio. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/14)
*/

img,
video {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/*
Ensure the default browser behavior of the `hidden` attribute.
*/

[hidden] {
  display: none;
}

*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  --tw-translate-x: 0;
  --tw-translate-y: 0;
  --tw-rotate: 0;
  --tw-skew-x: 0;
  --tw-skew-y: 0;
  --tw-scale-x: 1;
  --tw-scale-y: 1;
  --tw-pan-x: ;
  --tw-pan-y: ;
  --tw-pinch-zoom: ;
  --tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity;
  --tw-ordinal: ;
  --tw-slashed-zero: ;
  --tw-numeric-figure: ;
  --tw-numeric-spacing: ;
  --tw-numeric-fraction: ;
  --tw-ring-inset: ;
  --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;
  --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff;
  --tw-ring-color: rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);
  --tw-ring-offset-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-blur: ;
  --tw-brightness: ;
  --tw-contrast: ;
  --tw-grayscale: ;
  --tw-hue-rotate: ;
  --tw-invert: ;
  --tw-saturate: ;
  --tw-sepia: ;
  --tw-drop-shadow: ;
  --tw-backdrop-blur: ;
  --tw-backdrop-brightness: ;
  --tw-backdrop-contrast: ;
  --tw-backdrop-grayscale: ;
  --tw-backdrop-hue-rotate: ;
  --tw-backdrop-invert: ;
  --tw-backdrop-opacity: ;
  --tw-backdrop-saturate: ;
  --tw-backdrop-sepia: ;
}

.m-10 {
  margin: 2.5rem;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.h-80 {
  height: 20rem;
}

.w-96 {
  width: 24rem;
}

.w-28 {
  width: 7rem;
}

.flex-1 {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
}

.flex-row {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.overflow-x-hidden {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.overflow-y-hidden {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.overflow-x-scroll {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.overflow-y-scroll {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.border {
  border-width: 1px;
}

.border-l {
  border-left-width: 1px;
}

.pl-4 {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.perm-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

.perm-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.perm-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="m-10 flex h-80 w-96 flex-row flex-wrap overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll border perm-scroll">
  <div class="w-28 pl-4">
    <div>1111111</div>
    <div>1111111</div>
    <div>2222222</div>
    <div>2222222</div>
    <div>3333333</div>
    <div>3333333</div>
    <div>4444444</div>
    <div>4444444</div>
    <div>5555555</div>
    <div>5555555</div>
    <div>6666666</div>
    <div>6666666</div>
    <div>7777777</div>
    <div>7777777</div>
    <div>8888888</div>
    <div>8888888</div>
    <div>9999999</div>
    <div>9999999</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-1 overflow-y-hidden overflow-x-scroll border-l pl-4" style="scrollbar-gutter: stable both-edges">
    <div class="w-96">
      <div>1111111</div>
      <div>1111111</div>
      <div>2222222</div>
      <div>2222222</div>
      <div>3333333</div>
      <div>3333333</div>
      <div>4444444</div>
      <div>4444444</div>
      <div>5555555</div>
      <div>5555555</div>
      <div>6666666</div>
      <div>6666666</div>
      <div>7777777</div>
      <div>7777777</div>
      <div>8888888</div>
      <div>8888888</div>
      <div>9999999</div>
      <div>9999999</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I still see horizontal scrollbar all the way down though.

Comment: @nicholasnet What do you mean?

Comment: You can look at this example https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html as you see both scrollbars are visible all the time. This example have lot more component though. Another example is this https://bryntum.com/examples/grid/lockedcolumns/

Answer (score 1):

Ok I was able to make some progress using JavaScript. This is my solution so far.

```js
var pp = document.getElementById("pp");
document.getElementById("tt").addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
  
  pp.scrollTop = event.target.scrollTop;
  pp.scrollLeft = event.target.scrollLeft;
})
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* 1 */
  border-width: 0;
  /* 2 */
  border-style: solid;
  /* 2 */
  border-color: #e5e7eb;
  /* 2 */
}

::before,
::after {
  --tw-content: '';
}

/*
1. Use a consistent sensible line-height in all browsers.
2. Prevent adjustments of font size after orientation changes in iOS.
3. Use a more readable tab size.
4. Use the user's configured `sans` font-family by default.
*/

html {
  line-height: 1.5;
  /* 1 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  -moz-tab-size: 4;
  /* 3 */
  tab-size: 4;
  /* 3 */
  font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  /* 4 */
}

/*
1. Remove the margin in all browsers.
2. Inherit line-height from `html` so users can set them as a class directly on the `html` element.
*/

body {
  margin: 0;
  /* 1 */
  line-height: inherit;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
1. Add the correct height in Firefox.
2. Correct the inheritance of border color in Firefox. (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=190655)
3. Ensure horizontal rules are visible by default.
*/

hr {
  height: 0;
  /* 1 */
  color: inherit;
  /* 2 */
  border-top-width: 1px;
  /* 3 */
}

/*
Add the correct text decoration in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.
*/

abbr:where([title]) {
  -webkit-text-decoration: underline dotted;
      text-decoration: underline dotted;
}

/*
Remove the default font size and weight for headings.
*/

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
}

/*
Reset links to optimize for opt-in styling instead of opt-out.
*/

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

/*
Add the correct font weight in Edge and Safari.
*/

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

/*
1. Use the user's configured `mono` font family by default.
2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
*/

code,
kbd,
samp,
pre {
  font-family: ui-monospace, SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
  /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Add the correct font size in all browsers.
*/

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

/*
Prevent `sub` and `sup` elements from affecting the line height in all browsers.
*/

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

/*
1. Remove text indentation from table contents in Chrome and Safari. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=999088, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201297)
2. Correct table border color inheritance in all Chrome and Safari. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=935729, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195016)
3. Remove gaps between table borders by default.
*/

table {
  text-indent: 0;
  /* 1 */
  border-color: inherit;
  /* 2 */
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* 3 */
}

/*
1. Change the font styles in all browsers.
2. Remove the margin in Firefox and Safari.
3. Remove default padding in all browsers.
*/

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  font-size: 100%;
  /* 1 */
  line-height: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  color: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  margin: 0;
  /* 2 */
  padding: 0;
  /* 3 */
}

/*
Remove the inheritance of text transform in Edge and Firefox.
*/

button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}

/*
1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
2. Remove default button styles.
*/

button,
[type='button'],
[type='reset'],
[type='submit'] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* 1 */
  background-color: transparent;
  /* 2 */
  background-image: none;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Use the modern Firefox focus style for all focusable elements.
*/

:-moz-focusring {
  outline: auto;
}

/*
Remove the additional `:invalid` styles in Firefox. (https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/2f9eacd9d3d995c937b4251a5557d95d494c9be1/layout/style/res/forms.css#L728-L737)
*/

:-moz-ui-invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}

/*
Add the correct vertical alignment in Chrome and Firefox.
*/

progress {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/*
Correct the cursor style of increment and decrement buttons in Safari.
*/

::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto;
}

/*
1. Correct the odd appearance in Chrome and Safari.
2. Correct the outline style in Safari.
*/

[type='search'] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  /* 1 */
  outline-offset: -2px;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Remove the inner padding in Chrome and Safari on macOS.
*/

::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/*
1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
2. Change font properties to `inherit` in Safari.
*/

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* 1 */
  font: inherit;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Add the correct display in Chrome and Safari.
*/

summary {
  display: list-item;
}

/*
Removes the default spacing and border for appropriate elements.
*/

blockquote,
dl,
dd,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
hr,
figure,
p,
pre {
  margin: 0;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

legend {
  padding: 0;
}

ol,
ul,
menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*
Prevent resizing textareas horizontally by default.
*/

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

/*
1. Reset the default placeholder opacity in Firefox. (https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/3300)
2. Set the default placeholder color to the user's configured gray 400 color.
*/

input::placeholder,
textarea::placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
  /* 1 */
  color: #9ca3af;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Set the default cursor for buttons.
*/

button,
[role="button"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*
Make sure disabled buttons don't get the pointer cursor.
*/

:disabled {
  cursor: default;
}

/*
1. Make replaced elements `display: block` by default. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/14)
2. Add `vertical-align: middle` to align replaced elements more sensibly by default. (https://github.com/jensimmons/cssremedy/issues/14#issuecomment-634934210)
   This can trigger a poorly considered lint error in some tools but is included by design.
*/

img,
svg,
video,
canvas,
audio,
iframe,
embed,
object {
  display: block;
  /* 1 */
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Constrain images and videos to the parent width and preserve their intrinsic aspect ratio. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/14)
*/

img,
video {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/*
Ensure the default browser behavior of the `hidden` attribute.
*/

[hidden] {
  display: none;
}

*, ::before, ::after {
  --tw-translate-x: 0;
  --tw-translate-y: 0;
  --tw-rotate: 0;
  --tw-skew-x: 0;
  --tw-skew-y: 0;
  --tw-scale-x: 1;
  --tw-scale-y: 1;
  --tw-pan-x:  ;
  --tw-pan-y:  ;
  --tw-pinch-zoom:  ;
  --tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity;
  --tw-ordinal:  ;
  --tw-slashed-zero:  ;
  --tw-numeric-figure:  ;
  --tw-numeric-spacing:  ;
  --tw-numeric-fraction:  ;
  --tw-ring-inset:  ;
  --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;
  --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff;
  --tw-ring-color: rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);
  --tw-ring-offset-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-blur:  ;
  --tw-brightness:  ;
  --tw-contrast:  ;
  --tw-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-invert:  ;
  --tw-saturate:  ;
  --tw-sepia:  ;
  --tw-drop-shadow:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-blur:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-brightness:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-contrast:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-invert:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-opacity:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-saturate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-sepia:  ;
}

.m-10 {
  margin: 2.5rem;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.h-80 {
  height: 20rem;
}

.h-full {
  height: 100%;
}

.w-96 {
  width: 24rem;
}

.w-28 {
  width: 7rem;
}

.flex-1 {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
}

.flex-row {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.overflow-x-auto {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.overflow-x-hidden {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.overflow-y-hidden {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.border {
  border-width: 1px;
}

.border-l {
  border-left-width: 1px;
}

.pl-4 {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.pb-5 {
  padding-bottom: 1.25rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="m-10 flex w-96 flex-row flex-wrap overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-hidden border">
    <div class="h-80 w-28 pl-4">
        <div class="h-full overflow-y-hidden pb-5" id="pp">
            <div>1111111</div>
            <div>1111111</div>
            <div>2222222</div>
            <div>2222222</div>
            <div>3333333</div>
            <div>3333333</div>
            <div>4444444</div>
            <div>4444444</div>
            <div>5555555</div>
            <div>5555555</div>
            <div>6666666</div>
            <div>6666666</div>
            <div>7777777</div>
            <div>7777777</div>
            <div>8888888</div>
            <div>8888888</div>
            <div>9999999</div>
            <div>9999999</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="h-80 flex-1 overflow-x-auto border-l pb-5 pl-4" id="tt">
        <div class="h-full w-96">
            <div>1111111</div>
            <div>1111111</div>
            <div>2222222</div>
            <div>2222222</div>
            <div>3333333</div>
            <div>3333333</div>
            <div>4444444</div>
            <div>4444444</div>
            <div>5555555</div>
            <div>5555555</div>
            <div>6666666</div>
            <div>6666666</div>
            <div>7777777</div>
            <div>7777777</div>
            <div>8888888</div>
            <div>8888888</div>
            <div>9999999</div>
            <div>9999999</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I still prefer to do this in pure CSS if possible though.